# How to use Angular Signals with Material Table data source?

Tags: angular, signals, datasource

I'm trying to use new angular "feature" - signals. Inside some service I have a signal:

```
  failedTasks = computed(() => this.tasksState().failedTasks);
```

And then, I want to connect that signal to the table data source inside component. Previously, using observables, the code was like that:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<FailedTask>([]);

constructor(tasksService: TasksService){
    this.tasksService.failedTasks$.subscribe(tasks => this.dataSource.data = tasks)    
}
```

but with signals I have no idea how to do the same except using "effect" like that:

```
  constructor(tasksService: TasksService) {
    effect(() => {
      this.dataSource.data = this.tasksService.failedTasks();
    });
  }
```

What do you think about this approach? According to official docs "Effects are rarely needed in most application code", but how to implement the logic when we need to subscribe some source inside component.ts?

Comment: IMO, you're on the right track.  The only other way I would see tackling this is if you made `dataSource` a computed signal, which would mean instantiating the class with each update, which would not be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a way around this but all I have found is to turn the signal into an observable using the toObservable() function

```
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

failedTasks$ = toObservable(this.failedTasks());
```